# Get the delta days number instead of its format

Tags: python

I have bellow code, I want to get the delta days number instead of its format:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

com_day = now + datetime.timedelta(days=7.23)

delta_days = com_day - now

print(delta_days)  # there gets the `7 days, 5:31:12`
```

I want to get `7.23` instead of `7 days, 5:31:12`.

How to get the requirement?

Comment: have you tried delta_days.days ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract a datetime from another in Python, you get a timedelta object:

```
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> d1 = datetime (year=2015, month=6, day=1, hour=12, minute=30)
> d2 = datetime (year=2015, month=6, day=7, hour=18, minute=15)
> td = d2 - d1
> td
datetime.timedelta(6, 20700)
> type (td)
datetime.timedelta
```

Unfortunately, timedelta only returns the "parts" that make it up - days, seconds and microseconds:

```
> td.days, td.seconds, td.microseconds
(6, 20700, 0)
```

### The solution

In Python 3, you can divide one timedelta by another, which lets you do this:

```
> td / timedelta (days=1)
```

but not in Python 2.

However, timedelta has a method totalseconds, which returns the whole delta expressed as decimal seconds:

```
> td.total_seconds()
539100.0
> timedelta (days=1, microseconds=20).total_seconds()
86400.00002
```

Which lets us take the above solution and do this to work out the fractional days:

```
> td.total_seconds() / timedelta (days=1).total_seconds()
6.239583333333333
```

### Unresolved issues

If you to express a time difference as microseconds, minutes, hours etc. you're going to have to do some more math.

[From agapow.net](http://www.agapow.net/programming/python/convert-timedelta-to-float/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default **days()** method which would return the number of days. If you want the hours also in the day format. I hope the below code will be helpful.

```
delta_days.total_seconds()/86400
```

Similar to **days()** the **total_seconds()** will return the difference in seconds, so i divided it with number of seconds in a day.

hope it helps.

Happy Coding :)